# Do switches need any configuration?

Tags: switch, gns3

I created a testing gns3 project. When I click "console connect to all nodes", only connections to routers and vpcs were created. Why no connections to these switches? Does that mean switches don't need any configuration? I'm new in networking, btw.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic switches are entirely self-learning (bridges), they don't need any configuration.

Managed switches should be configured to require a password for all management interfaces (SSH, telnet, web, SNMP, ...).

All more advanced features like STP, VLANs, LAG, port-level authentication, ACLs and of course L3 switching require configuration as well.

Your setup likely lacks the remote routes on each router so that e.g. R1 knows that 192.168.200.0/24 is located behind R2. You can set those statically or by using a routing protocol between the routers. Also, the PCs need to have their local router set as default gateway.

Comment: Also the switches in GNS3 are basic switches. (assuming they are the built-in switches, not some virtual appliance)

Answer (score 1):

In GNS3, switches are basic devices that need no configuration.  As @zac67 points out, you still need to configure routing (static or dynamic) between R1 and R2.